# an arithmetic sequence contains infinite primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

> Let $\{u_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ be an arithmetic sequence defined by $u_n=an+b
>  \quad  (a,b\in\mathbb{N}^*)$.
>
> a) Let $a=6$. Give 2 values of $b\leq 6$ s.t for each such value of $b$, $\{u_n\}$ has
> infinite primes.
>
> b) Let $a=10$. Prove that there are
> infinite values of $b$ s.t for each such value of $b$, $\{u_n\}$ has
> infinite primes.

I have done part a) so far (indeed there are infinite primes of the form $6k+1, 6k+5$).
I'm stuck at part b). I don't want to use [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) for this problem. Could anyone have any idea to tackle this problem without mentioning Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: The condition $gcd(a,b)=1$ is missing

Comment: Well, you only need to find _one_ such $b$, because then you can add any multiple of $10$ to it to get another $b$.

Comment: @Peter: No it isn't $-$ for every such $b$, the condition $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is autmatically satisfied.

Comment: Are you actually Alex Nguyen?  who used to work at Google?

Comment: @Doug Nguyễn is a very common Vietnamese last name

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single value of $b$ then the family of $10k + b$ also satisfies, so one only need to prove that there is one such b.

Let $S=\{0,1,2,3,..,9\}$. Let $N_b=\{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid n=10k+b,b\in S,k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be the set of natural number in the sequence $10k+b$, $P$ is the set of primes, $P_b = P \cup N_b$ is the set of primes in sequence $10k+b$.

Short proof:
Assume that $\left| P_b\right|$ is finite for each $b$, then we have
$$\sum{\left| P_b\right|} \geq \left| \bigcup{P_b}\right| = \left| \bigcup{P\cap N_b}\right| = \left| P \cap \mathbb{N}\right|=|P|$$

But this means there are finitely many primes, which is wrong, so there is at least one $b$ such that the set $P_b$ is infinite $\square$

Explanation: since every prime must belong to one and only one of the sets $P_b$, the sum of their sizes must equal to the number of primes. Therefore at least one of them must be infinite, hence it completes the proof